# I made a PHP code to display data, but it doesnt display anything. How to fix this? (PDO)

Tags: php, sql

The code you see here I supposed to load data from the database and display the data I asked for in the query and display this.

I want to display 'rol'. How can I make this work?

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$query = "SELECT rol FROM users WHERE username = $username";

$stm = $con->prepare($query);
$stm->execute();
$result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    echo $pers->rol;
}
?>
```

Comment: So you have some code and desired behaviour, alright; what is the actual behaviour? You're asking "How can I make this work?", so please describe what happens currently: do you get any errors? What have you tried to debug? Any var dumps at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very purpose of prepared statements is to "prepare" them, by declaring what a variable will be before you submit it to the database.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$query = "SELECT rol FROM users WHERE username = :username";

$stm = $con->prepare($query);
$stm->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stm->execute();
$result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($result as $pers) {
    echo $pers->rol;
}

?>
```

Therefore, as above, you must declare the parameters you are sending in bindParam, rather than placing the variable in the query itself.

Comment: Call to undefined function `bind_para`

Comment: Please note `bind_param()` is not a PDO function

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile My mistake. Amended.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly without the '$stm->close();'

Comment: @h34ksjaa Perfect, I've removed that. If you are satisfied this is the answer, please mark it as accepted, so that others will know this answer worked.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this exmple

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$sth->bind_param("s", $username);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

this print_r return all column in database if you want one column you can use this

```
foreach($result as $item){
echo $item->rol;
}
```

good luck